# How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, arel

I want to do something like:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME LIKE '%Smith%';
```

My attempt in Arel:

```
# params[:query] = 'Smith'
User.where("name like '%?%'", params[:query]).to_sql
```

However, this becomes:

```
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE NAME LIKE '%'Smith'%';
```

Arel wraps the query string 'Smith' correctly, but because this is a LIKE statement it doesnt work.

How does one do a LIKE query in Arel?

P.S. Bonus--I am actually trying to scan two fields on the table, both name and description, to see if there are any matches to the query. How would that work?

Comment: I updated the arel answer for the bonus.

Answer (score 291, accepted):

This is how you perform a like query in arel:

```
users = User.arel_table
User.where(users[:name].matches("%#{user_name}%"))
```

PS:

```
users = User.arel_table
query_string = "%#{params[query]}%"
param_matches_string =  ->(param){ 
  users[param].matches(query_string) 
} 
User.where(param_matches_string.(:name)\
                       .or(param_matches_string.(:description)))
```

Comment: That's correct. Either approach should work. But this one uses the Arel API more directly. This is important if you want to use the full power of Arel, e.g. to construct complex queries.

Comment: Unlike using `where("name like ?", ...)`, this approach is more portable across different databases. For example, it would result in `ILIKE` being used in a query against a Postgres db.

Comment: is this protected against SQL injections?

Comment: I do not see any reason why it would make sense to implement the 'matches' method without escaping the provided input within. It must be safe against SQL Injections. Anyway, if you're keen on that, you may always verify it within the code: https://github.com/brynary/arel/tree/master/lib/arel I am also curious about the answer, and I did not find the code for the Arel::Nodes::Matcher class.

Comment: Arel::Nodes::Matches is defined here. https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/master/lib/arel/nodes/binary.rb

Comment: This does NOT protect fully against SQL injection. Try setting user_name to "%". The query will return matches

Comment: s there any update to this in light of Rails 4? Something like User.where(:name ....

Comment: @MichaelKMadison it was added, but later reverted (see https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8d02afeaee8993bd0fde69687fdd9bf30921e805). There is a lengthy discussion about the motives in the commit comments.

Comment: I tried to sql inject using params directly, `User.where(users[:name].matches("%#{params[:user_name]}%"))`, I tried `TRUNCATE users;` and other such queries and nothing happened on the sql side. Looks safe to me.

Comment: Also if you don't know you can try from console via `User.where(users[:name].matches("%TRUNCATE users;%")).to_sql` This will show that it is escaped and contained in single quotes.

Comment: Use ```.gsub(/[%_]/, '\\\\\0')``` for escaping MySql wildcard chars.

Comment: I'm on Rails 4.0.0, but NoMethodError: undefined method `like' for #<ActiveRecord::QueryMethods::WhereChain:0x007fe03b9dd0a0>

Comment: +Tom Rossi : you are right. It was just a proposal and it has been rolled back. sorry for the mess: https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/8d02afeaee8993bd0fde69687fdd9bf30921e805

Comment: This seems to be a better option compared to passing an Array because it avoids any ambiguous column references.

Comment: Rails has `sanitize_sql_like` to safely escape wildcards.

Comment: both Arel and `LIKE ?` protect against arbitrary SQL injection but not against wildcard injection: https://github.com/rails/arel/blob/6cf061ed6f3f9c8128385765c07eaa4f8a43bd34/test/visitors/test_to_sql.rb#L299-L302 
`matches("#{user.name}%")` is risky if user called himself `%`; `matches("#{sanitize_sql_like(user.name)}%")` is safe.

Comment: You can also use `matches(term, nil true)` to do a `LIKE` instead of an `ILIKE`. If you are doing an `ILIKE` on an indexed column (you'll want a  `BTREE` index for `LIKE`/`ILIKE`), the first character needs to be a non-alphabetic character (a character that cannot be affected by upper/lower case conversion).

Answer (score 118):

Try

```
User.where("name like ?", "%#{params[:query]}%").to_sql
```

PS.

```
q = "%#{params[:query]}%"
User.where("name like ? or description like ?", q, q).to_sql
```

Aaand it's been a long time but @cgg5207 added a modification (mostly useful if you're going to search long-named or multiple long-named parameters or you're too lazy to type)

```
q = "%#{params[:query]}%"
User.where("name like :q or description like :q", :q => q).to_sql
```

or

```
User.where("name like :q or description like :q", :q => "%#{params[:query]}%").to_sql
```

Comment: How does Rails know not to escape `%` in the substituted string? It seems like if you only wanted a one-sided wildcard, there's nothing stopping the user from submitting a query value that includes `%` at both ends (I know that in practice, Rails prevents `%` from showing up in a query string, but it seems like there should be protection against this at the ActiveRecord level).

Comment: Isn't this vulnerable to SQL injection attacks?

Comment: @Behrang no 8) User.where("name like %#{params[:query]}% or description like%#{params[:query]}%").to_sql would be vulnerable, but, in the format I show, Rails escapes params[:query]

Comment: Sorry for offtopic. I have the sql git of method `to_sql` or arel manager, how to execute the sql on db?

Comment: Model.where(to_sql_result)

Comment: New to Rails. Just wondering why `where('foo LIKE ?', '%bar%')` works but `where('foo LIKE ?' => '%bar%')` doesn't - or should it and I'm missing something?

Answer (score 3):

Reuben Mallaby's answer can be shortened further to use parameter bindings:

```
User.where("name like :kw or description like :kw", :kw=>"%#{params[:query]}%").to_sql
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget escape user input.
You can use `ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_like(w)`

```
query = "%#{ActiveRecord::Base.sanitize_sql_like(params[:query])}%"
matcher = User.arel_table[:name].matches(query)
User.where(matcher)
```

You can simplify in `models/user.rb`

```
def self.name_like(word)
  where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{sanitize_sql_like(word)}%"))
end
```