# How to make keywords filtering queries in Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def autocomplete
    @location=Location.find_by_sql("select * from locations where name like ?;",['%'+params[:term]+'%'])
    render  json: @location
  end
end
```

I think query like this is not working as expected:
select * from locations where name like '%XXXX%';

Neither can I wrote code like this:
    @location=Location.find_by_sql("select * from locations where name like '?';",
 the function will fail to recognize the params

So how could I implement such keywords filtering queries?

Comment: Why do you use find_by_sql for such a basic query ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
@location = Location.where("name LIKE ?", "%#{params[:term]}%")
```