# Translate postgres VARCHAR query into ruby activerecord

Tags: ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I need to translate the following postgreSQL query into an activerecord ruby query.

```
select * 
from my_table 
where (my_time between '2010-12-27 00:00:00' and '2011-01-28 00:00:00') 
  and (my_time::TIME)::VARCHAR like '12:00:00.%';
```

This pulls out the 12:00:00.% piece of data for each day. I can do time range part, but don't know how to translate the second half of the query.

Thanks

Comment: Your cast might not work properly with different language settings. You should use to_char() with a format mask rather than the implicit cast.

Comment: Is it possible to translate this into a ruby activerecord statement?

Comment: Maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-TABLE) to convert your timestamp to the appropriate string form and strip off the fractional seconds at the same time:

```
where to_char(my_time, 'HH24:MM:SS') = '12:00:00'
...
```

The ActiveRecord version of that is pretty simple:

```
MyTable.where("to_char(my_time, 'HH24:MM:SS') = '12:00:00'")
```

Then chain in your existing BETWEEN check.

You could also use [`extract`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) to check each time component separately:

```
where extract(hour   from my_time) = 12
  and extract(minute from my_time) =  0
  and extract(second from my_time) =  0
  ...
```

The ActiveRecord version of that would be:

```
MyTable.where('extract(hour   from my_time) = ?', 12)
       .where('extract(minute from my_time) = ?',  0)
       .where('extract(second from my_time) = ?',  0)
```

You'd have to ask EXPLAIN to see which version works best.