# rails refactoring a query for correct sql injection

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

this is the original query

```
where(countries.map{|c| "zones.countries LIKE '%#{c}%'"}.join(' OR '))
```

now i would rewrite this query with ? operator like this

```
where(countries.map{|c| "zones.countries LIKE ?", "%#{c}%"}.join(' OR '))
```

but it doesn't work. Any suggestion?
thx

Comment: Try this previous SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3

Comment: @davide - One performance tip for the query you are writing. 1. Looping on the query is not a good idea 2. Using Like clause with multiple OR's will slow down the query. Try to convert that Like to = and fetch the records. This query wont scale on a large data set. Just throwing out this idea let me know ho it sounds to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
where(countries.map { |c| "zones.countries LIKE ?" }.join(" OR "), *countries.map{ |c| "%#{c}%"})
```

You can replace the first argument of the `where` above with something like this to avoid one loop

```
("zones.countries LIKE ? OR " * countries.size).gsub(/ OR $/, '')
```