# Rails activerecord LIKE AND clause error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Here is an activerecord query i'm trying to use in rails

```
q = "Manchester"
b = "John Smith"

Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["city ? AND name like ?", q, b])
```

but i get this error in rails console

ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: near "'Manchester'": syntax error: SELECT            "model".* FROM "model"  WHERE (city 'Manchester' AND name like 'John Smith')

Please help!

Comment: `.. where city 'Manchester' name like 'John Smith'` <-- hmm?

Answer (score 8):

You missed `LIKE` for `city`.

```
Model.where('city LIKE ? AND name LIKE ?', "%#{q}%", "%#{b}%");
```

Comment: or maybe should using arel to say LIKE, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3

Answer (score 6):

You can also use this syntax which is a lot more readable than trying to figure out which `?` goes with which variable. I mean if you have 1 or 2 it's fine, but once you have more it gets pretty ugly.

```
Model.where("city LIKE :city AND name LIKE :name", { city: "%#{q}%", name: "%#{b}%"  })
```

The placeholders and hash key can be anything you like as long as they match (don't use `:city` and then `hamster:` in the hash key for example).

The nice thing about this is that you can also use one variable for multiple searches:

```
where("user LIKE :term OR email LIKE :term OR friends LIKE :term", { term: "%#{params[:term]}%"})
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Model.find(:all, :conditions => ["city = ? AND name like ?", q, b])
```

Comment: Consider pointing out the difference/issue, especially when it's subtly.