# Where like on ruby table, SQL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, where-clause, sql-like

I'm trying to do a filter with a where clause and indicating the table.

Currently I'm using this, that only works if it's the exact same username:

```
@diagnostics = Diagnostic.scoped

@diagnostics = @diagnostics.includes(:user).where(tbl_users: { username: "#{params[:search]}" }) if params[:search_by] == 'by_user'
```

I'm trying to do a search where it can be use with a like, and its not working:

```
@diagnostics = Diagnostic.scoped

@diagnostics = @diagnostics.includes(:user).where(tbl_users: { username: "%#{params[:search]}%" }) if params[:search_by] == 'by_user'
```

Any solutions ?

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at [How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails-3). That should answer your question.

Comment: The problem of doing .where('QUERY') is that I no longer indicate the table. 
Though I tried to declare the variable before using it on the query. And it didn't worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
@diagnostics = Diagnostic.scoped

@diagnostics = @diagnostics.includes(:user).where("users.username like '%?%'", params[:search]) if params[:search_by] == 'by_user'
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```
@diagnostics = Diagnostic.scoped

@diagnostics = @diagnostics.includes(:user).all(:conditions => ['user_name LIKE ?', "%#{@q}%"])
```