# How to select all records that start with certain string?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have several records for which `title` starts with:

- Nick1
- Nick2
- Nick3
- Othername1

How can I select all the records of which the title starts with "Nick" and have them rendered in the correct order? Something like:

```
@records = Record.where(title starts with: params[:title_name])
render json: @records
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LIKE` operator here:

```
@records = Record.where('title LIKE ?', "#{params[:title_name]}%").order(:title)
```

I would prefer to put these into a scope:

```
scope :title_search, ->(title){ where('title LIKE ?', "#{title}%") }
```

and call it via:

```
@records = Record.title_search(params[:title_name])
```

Comment: For “**started** with certain string” the correct placement of a percent sign would be the opposite: `'title LIKE ?', "#{title}%"`.

Comment: @mudasobwa thanks a lot. you're right. i updated the answer and correct my mistake

Comment: Thanks, it works but I'm having a problem with capital sensitivity. The title in the params is without a capital, while in the database the title has a capital. As a results it returns no records. Is there a way to solve this and make the 'query' capital insensitive?

Comment: Try `Record.where('LOWER(title) LIKE ?', "#{params[:title_name].downcase}%").order(:title)` to be caseinsensitive. The SQL function could also be `LCASE`. Depends on your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can try  [Searchlogic](http://rdoc.info/projects/binarylogic/searchlogic) .

Then it's as easy as:

```
@search = Record.new_search(params[:search])
@search.condition.title_starts_with = "Nick"
@models = @search.all
```

Or you can try

```
Record.where("title LIKE :prefix", prefix: "#{prefix}%")
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using arel as in "[How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails)"

```
records = Record.arel_table
Record.where records[:title].matches("#{params[:title_name]}%")
```