# Specific search implementation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

So I'm trying to improve the search feature for my app

My model relationships/associations are like so (many>one, one=one):

- Clients < Projects < Activities = Assignments = Users
- Assignments < Tasks

Tasks table has only a foreign key to assignments.

Search params look something like this:

```
params[:search]==User: 'user_handle', Client: 'client_name', Project: 'project_name', Activity: 'activity_name'
```

So I need to porbably search Clients.where().tasks, Projects.where().tasks and so on.
Then I need to somehow concatenate those queries and get rid of all the duplicate results. How to do that in practice however, I have no clue.

I've been hitting my head against a brick wall with this and internet searches didn't really help... so any help is greatly apreciated. Its probably a simple solution too...

I am on rails 4.2.5 sqlite for dev pg for production

Comment: Hey, I could not understand if you mean `inheritance` or `association` by the `<` operator.. please. I thing rewrite would be good

Comment: edited, I meant associations(thought they were called relationships in rails) so for instance:
Projects has a foreign key client_id
Project model has a belongs_to associations
Client model has a has_many association

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things I would change/recommend based on the code in your own answer:

1. Move the search queries into scopes on each model class
2. Prefer AREL over raw SQL when composing queries ([here's a quick
   guide](http://danshultz.github.io/talks/mastering_activerecord_arel/#/))
3. Enhance rails to use some sort of `or` when querying Models

The changes I suggest will enable you to do something like this:

```
search = search_params

tasks = Tasks.all
tasks = tasks.or.user_handle_matches(handle) if (handle = search[:user].presence)
tasks = tasks.or.client_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:client].presence)
tasks = tasks.or.project_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:project].presence)
tasks = tasks.or.activity_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:activity].presence)
@tasks = tasks.uniq
```

First, convert each of your queries to a scope on your models.  This enables you to reuse your scopes later:

```
class User
  scope :handle_matches, ->(handle) {
    where(arel_table[:handle].matches("%#{handle}%"))
  }
end

class Client
  scope :name_matches, ->(name) {
    where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{name}%"))
  }
end

class Project
  scope :name_matches, ->(name) {
    where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{name}%"))
  }
end

class Activity
  scope :name_matches, ->(name) {
    where(arel_table[:name].matches("%#{name}%"))
  }
end
```

You can then use these scopes on your `Task` model to allow for better searching capabilities.  For each of the scopes on `Task` we are doing an join (inner join) on a relationship and using the scope to limit the results of the join:

```
class Task
  belongs_to :assignment
  has_one :user, :through => :assignment
  has_one :activity, :through => :assignment
  has_one :project, :through => :activity

  scope :user_handle_matches, ->(handle) {
    joins(:user).merge( User.handle_matches(handle) )
  }

  scope :client_name_matches, ->(name) {
    joins(:client).merge( Client.name_matches(name) )
  }

  scope :activity_name_matches, ->(name) {
    joins(:activity).merge( Activity.name_matches(name) )
  }

  scope :project_name_matches, ->(name) {
    joins(:project).merge( Project.name_matches(name) )
  }
end
```

The final problem to solve is `or`ing the results.  Rails 4 and below don't really allow this out of the box but there are gems and code out there to allow this functionality.

I often include the code in [this GitHub gist](https://gist.github.com/j-mcnally/250eaaceef234dd8971b) in an initializer to allow `or`ing of scopes.  The code allows you to do things like `Person.where(name: 'John').or.where(name: 'Jane')`.

Many other options are discussed in this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4430578/848668).

If you don't want include random code and gems, another option is to pass an array of ids into the where clause.  This generates a query similar to `SELECT * FROM tasks WHERE id IN (1, 4, 5, ...)`:

```
tasks = []
tasks << Tasks.user_handle_matches(handle) if (handle = search[:user].presence)
tasks << tasks.or.client_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:client].presence)
tasks << tasks.or.project_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:project].presence)
tasks << tasks.or.activity_name_matches(name) if (name = search[:activity].presence)

# get the matching id's for each query defined above
# this is the catch, each call to `pluck` is another hit of the db
task_ids = tasks.collect {|query| query.pluck(:id) }
tasks_ids.uniq!

@tasks = Tasks.where(id: tasks_ids)
```

Answer (score 0):

So I solved it, it is supper sloppy however.

first I wrote a method

```
def add_res(ar_obj)
    ar_obj.each do |o|
        res += o.tasks
    end
    return res
end
```

then I wrote my search logic like so

```
if !search_params[:user].empty?
    query = add_res(User.where('handle LIKE ?', "%#{search_params[:user]}%"))
    @tasks.nil? ? @tasks=query : @tasks=@tasks&query
end
if !search_params[:client].empty?
    query = add_res(Client.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search_params[:client]}%"))
    @tasks.nil? ? @tasks=query : @tasks=@tasks&query
end
if !search_params[:project].empty?
    query = add_res(Project.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search_params[:project]}%"))
    @tasks.nil? ? @tasks=query : @tasks=@tasks&query
end
if !search_params[:activity].empty?
    query = add_res(Activity.where('name LIKE ?', "%#{search_params[:activity]}%"))
    @tasks.nil? ? @tasks=query : @tasks=@tasks&query
end
if @tasks.nil?
    @tasks=Task.all
end
@tasks=@tasks.uniq
```

If someone can provide a better answer I would be forever greatful