# Find record with hash value in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have one table called `posts`

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
   t.text     "values"
end
```

My record values are

```
#<Post id: 1, values: {"p1"=>"1", "p2"=>"xyz"}>
#<Post id: 2, values: {"p1"=>"1", "p2"=>"abc"}>
```

I want to find record from post where `values[:p2] = "abc"`

Comment: Why are you storing hash values in your DB? Why not create two columns, one for `p1` and one for `p2`. Then you can query it with `posts.where(p2: 'abc')`.

Comment: Wait.. what?

The values are a JSON but stored as a text? that is really ugly and unusable. do these p1, p2.. need to be generic? and why don't you use `t.json`?

Comment: Rails also have datatype to to store hash values it is  :hstore, you can use it like t.hstore.

Comment: The answer depends on which database you're using. There also might not be a *good* answer.

Comment: @nicholas79171 you are right
But if i want to find using hash value then what will be the solution

Comment: @Azolo database is postgres

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, your best bet is using the [`LIKE` query](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4430619/3251199) to get columns that contain your substring:

```
Posts.where("values like %\"p2\"=>\"abc\"%")
```

The above query has not been tested, but should get the rows that contain `"p2"=>"abc"`.

But as I mentioned in the comments, I **do not** recommend this solution. Configuring your table like so would be much better:

```
create_table "posts", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.text     "p1"
  t.text     "p2"
end
```

Then your new query becomes

```
Posts.where(p2: 'abc')
```

which is not only much cleaner, it will be much quicker.

Comment: Did you get an error? Or just nothing back? And why do you want to keep your database set up that way?