# Ruby on rails - adding a select tag to search different fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm working on a search feature for an app, I have a a basic search working, however, I need to be able to have a select field to select what the user searches.

i.e If I have a select tag with the following:

Name, Currency, Company name

I need to be able to select the dropdown option and then enter my search term, here is what my form looks like
[image]

My form looks like this

```rb
<%= form_tag contacts_path, method: :get do %>
  <div class='l-inline-row-block'>
    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= select_tag(:qs, options_for_select(['name', 'customers', 'suppliers', 'tags'], selected: params[:qs])) %>
    </div>

    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= search_field_tag :search, params[:search] %>
    </div>

    <div class='l-inline-col'>
      <%= submit_tag submit_text, { class: 'no_print' } %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following in the controller index method

```rb
 @contacts = Contact.search(params[:search])
```

and the following in the model

```rb
def self.search(search)
  if search
    contacts = Contact.order(:id)
    contacts = contacts.where("name like ?", "%#{search}%") if search.present?
    contacts
  else
    contacts = Contact.all
  end
end
```

I have looked into https://railscasts.com/episodes/111-advanced-search-form-revised but I don't need a separate search page I need all the searching to happen on the index page.

Any help would be great.

**Update**

I've use the following solution from @max (thank you), however, running into some other issues:

Here is the db structure:

```
  create_table "contacts", force: :cascade, options: "ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8" do |t|
    t.integer  "customer_account_id"
    t.integer  "supplier_account_id"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "salutation"
    t.string   "title"
    t.string   "phone"
    t.string   "mobile"
    t.string   "business_email"
    t.string   "private_email"
    t.date     "date_of_birth"
    t.string   "spouse"
    t.string   "address_1"
    t.string   "address_2"
    t.string   "address_3"
    t.string   "address_4"
    t.string   "postcode"
    t.text     "other_information",   limit: 65535
    t.integer  "created_by"
    t.integer  "updated_by"
    t.string   "contact_type"
    t.integer  "assigned_to"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "company_name"
    t.string   "web_address"
    t.string   "second_phone"
    t.integer  "prospect_strength"
    t.boolean  "obsolete"
    t.string   "url"
    t.index ["obsolete"], name: "index_contacts_on_obsolete", using: :btree
  end
```

Each contacts record has a `contact_type` so not sure if we could search off that but need both customer and supplier options.

[image]

were using `acts_as_taggable` for the tags which need to be searchable.

Here is the current method that the previous search uses if this helps

```rb
def quick_search_fields
  @quick_search_fields = [
    {
      col_name: 'name',
      title: 'name',
      column_names: ['contacts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'customer_name',
      title: 'customer',
      search_tables: [:customer],
      column_names: ['accounts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'supplier_name',
      title: 'supplier',
      search_tables: [:supplier],
      column_names: ['accounts.name']
    },
    {
      col_name: 'tags',
      title: 'tags',
      tags: true,
      tagged: Contact
    }
  ]
end
```

Here is my `select_tag` `<%= select_tag(:qs, options_for_select(['name', 'customers', 'suppliers', 'tag_list'], selected: params[:qs])) %>`
+
the changes in max's solution. However, here's the error that I'm getting when searching suppliers, customers and tags.

```
Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'contacts.customers' in 'where clause': SELECT  `contacts`.* FROM `contacts` WHERE (`contacts`.`suppliers` LIKE '%john%') ORDER BY id asc LIMIT 20 OFFSET 0
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the arity of your search method to 2 and construct a LIKE query with a dynamic column name:

```
class Contact < ApplicationRecord
  # Prevents sql injections
  SEARCHABLE_FIELDS = ['name', 'customers', 'suppliers', 'tags']

  def self.search(field, query)
    if field.present? && query.present? && SEARCHABLE_FIELDS.include?(field)
      # WHERE contacts.field LIKE '%?%'
      where(arel_attribute(field).matches("%#{query}%"))
    else
      all
    end
  end
end
```

```
@contacts = Contact.search(params[:qs], params[:search])
```

If you want to vary the logic performed by the search depending on the field I would really suggest you extract this functionality out of the model into a seperate object or look at gems such as Ransack.

See:

- [Intro to Arel
  by Tingting Li](https://buildingvts.com/intro-to-arel-542a078028aa)
- [How to do a LIKE query in Arel and Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4430578/how-to-do-a-like-query-in-arel-and-rails)

Comment: Rails provides a convenience method for `arel_table[column]` called `arel_attribute` which feels a bit less esoteric IMO.(Also it accepts a `String` or `Symbol`) e.g. `arel_attribute(field).matches("%#{query}%")`

Comment: I wasn't aware of that. Thanks @engineersmnky

Comment: I’ll give this a try tomorrow thank you, this is the basic search that I’m rebuilding the advance search we have is around 12 different options etc so I hope I can add onto the above.

Comment: @max I'm getting the following error undefined method `includes?' for ["name", "customers", "suppliers", "tags"]:Array
Hint: `includes?` is being called on a `Array` object, which might not be the type of object you were expecting.

Comment: Ah sorry should be `.include?`. That one always trips me up as it's so ungrammatical...

Comment: Yeah that trips me up too, I'll make some edit to the question as I'm still running into some errors @max

Comment: Well provided that schema you can't reasonably expect to be able to search all those things without a lot more logic. This simple LIKE query will only work for VARCHAR / text columns in your contacts table. For associations you need to use a different approach using a join. This is really outside the scope of your original question and should be treated as a separate question.

Comment: You also at least have to make sure that the options actually match up with the names of the columns in the table which is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood what you want to achieve, I think you could do it all in the controller like this :

```
def index
  if params[:search].present?
    case params[:qs]
    when 'name'
      result = 'your query for name'
    when 'customers'
      result = 'your query for customers'
    when 'suppliers'
      result = 'your query for suppliers'
    else
      result = 'your query for tags'
    end
    result
   else
     a default query if no search
   end
end
```

Comment: I’ll give this a try tomorrow thank you, this is the basic search that I’m rebuilding the advance search we have is around 12 different options etc so I hope I can add onto the above.